# Event? for TimeChanged in Windows

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

In the previous version of my Application to enable capture that the time had been changed in Windows I implemented an IMessageFilter to capture WM_ that is sent by windows when the time has changed.

I know that now with .NET 4 (previously I was using .NET 2 (with reflection) to "ResetTimeZone" I can just call ClearCachedData.

What I'm hoping is that there is some Event that I can attach to in the BCL which I may not have seen that can report the Time has been changed.

If not, I'll just stick with my existing Filter. Does such an event exist? Similar to the `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged`

```
Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message) As Boolean Implements 
    System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case 30
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()
            'ResetTimeZone()
            RaiseEvent TimeChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
        Case Else
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

[SystemEvents.TimeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged.aspx)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much, can't believe how much effort I put in to that hacky method and this has existed since the beginning of .NET